# Traps in the Jobava Attack

Tags: opening, london-system

Are there any known early tactical traps in the so-called Jobava Attack (1.d4 d5 2.Nc3 Nf6 3.Bf4) for both sides? Leaving out the Barry Attack (early g6 by Black).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some mistakes you should avoid while playing the so-called Jobava Attack.

3...c5 is one good answer, and as you can see 4.Nb5 is not working here.

The video below also shows many tactics in the middlegame, after other continuations like 3...c6 and 3...e6.

After 14...Rfc8?! 15.Nf5 the best response is taking the knight and accepting a shattered pawn structure. Otherwise white is much better (+1.3 in the least: https://lichess.org/analysis/standard/r1r3k1/3bqppp/p3pn2/np1p2B1/3P4/P1NB3P/1PPQ1PP1/3RR1K1_b_-_-_1_17)

```
      [StartPly "5"]

      [FEN ""]
      1. d4 d5 2. Nc3 Nf6 3. Bf4 c5 4. e3 (4. Nb5? Qa5+
5. Nc3 cxd4 6. Qxd4 Nc6 7. Qa4 Qxa4 8. Nxa4 Nb4 (8...e5)) cxd4
5. exd4 a6 6. Bd3 Nc6 7. Nge2 e6 8. Qd2 b5 9. O-O Be7 10. a3 Bd7 11. h3 O-O 12. Rfe1 Na5 13. Rad1 Qb6 14. Ng3 Rfc8?! (14... Rfe8!) 15. Nf5 Qd8? (15...exf5) 16.Nxe7+ Qxe7 17.Bg5
```

You can find a more detailed video explanation here:

https://youtu.be/5joSsNpJ9qw

Related games:

https://lichess.org/OfUGrtY6

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1838817

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1857787

Answer (score 2):

I once had someone play 3...Nc6, which is dubious but not immediately disastrous. But after 4.Nb5, any response other than 4...e5 and White has a decisive advantage. This is almost the mirror image of the knight attack against the two knights Italian game.

Comment: Why "almost" ? This is exactly the mirror image of 4.Ng5 is the two knights defense.

Comment: The king and queen are not mirrored! :-) This is not just to be pedantic but because there are no mirror-image counterparts to the Fried Liver Attack or the Traxler Counterattack. For example after 5.dxe5, 5...Nxe5 is obviously not an option as White can simply play 6.Bxe5, while in the Two Knights Defense, 5...Nxd5 is not nearly as bad, even if risky.